# How to resolve this dictionary KeyError?

Tags: python, text

I am trying to compare `string2` words in `string1` and if they are found, I am trying to add the word and their frequency into a dictionary. but I received this error which means that key does not exist.

```
string1 = 'here i i go and will see see sun'
string2 = 'i will go'
found = {}
new_words = {}

for word in string2.split():
    if word in string1.split():
        found[word] += 1
    else:
        new_words[word] +=1
```

I got this error.

```
KeyError: 'i'
```

I am trying to get Expect output as: these are the words which consist of `string2` and they are found in `string1` and their frequency:

```
found {'i': 2, 'will': 1, 'go': 1}
```

`new_words` are those words which are not in `string2` but they are in `string1`, so they are `new_words`.

```
new_words {'here': 1, 'see': 2, 'sun': 1, 'and':1}
```

I am newbie to programming.Can someone help me solve this simple problem? I cannot store keys before because I don't know which words will be there in strings and their frequency.

Comment: `new_words[word] +=1` won't work because you're trying to increment a value stored against a key that doesn't exist. Did you mean `new_words[word] = 1` instead?

Comment: @roganjosh i am trying to compare string2 words frequency in string1 and want to add them to found dictionary, and the remaining words in string1 and their frequency to new_words dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more option - you could use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects)

```
from collections import defaultdict

string1 = 'here i go and i will see sun and enjoy the sunny day'
string2 = 'i will not go'
found = defaultdict(int)
new_words = defaultdict(int)
for word in string2.split():
    if word in string1.split():
        found[word] += 1
    else:
        new_words[word] +=1
```

**UPDATE**

To solve your second problem you should exchange `string2` and `string1` in `for` loop. You should iterate over all words in `string1` and check them in `string2`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

string1 = 'here i go and i will see sun and enjoy the sunny day'
string2 = 'i will not go'
found = defaultdict(int)
new_words = defaultdict(int)

for word in string1.split():
    if word in string2.split():
        found[word] += 1
    else:
        new_words[word] +=1

found
Out[66]: defaultdict(int, {'go': 1, 'i': 2, 'will': 1})

new_words
Out[67]: 
defaultdict(int,
            {'and': 2,
             'day': 1,
             'enjoy': 1,
             'here': 1,
             'see': 1,
             'sun': 1,
             'sunny': 1,
             'the': 1})
```

Comment: i am trying to compare string2 words frequency in string1 and want to add them to found dictionary, and the remaining words in string1 and their frequency to new_words dictionary

Comment: your solution works fine for string2. I am trying to compare string2 words with string1

Comment: @robbin Could you provide excepted output?

Comment: yes i will edit my question and will come back in a while

Comment: I added the expected output

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to add to a value that may or may not exist in the dictionary. Use `get()` instead to ensure safe execution:

```
found[word] = found.get(word, default=0) + 1
```

and

```
new_words[word] = new_words.get(word, default=0) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot increment an integer value that does not exist yet, which is the case the first time the word is encountered.

```
for word in string2.split():
    if word in string1.split():
        if word not in found.keys():
            found[word] = 1
        else:
            found[word] += 1
    else:
        if word not in new_words.keys():
            new_words[word] = 1
        else:
            new_words[word] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to increment (+1) a key that does not exist in your dictionnary. You should check first if the key exist. with:

```
if key in dict:
     dict[key]+=1
else:
     dict[key]=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You get a `KeyError` because the key doesn't yet (`found[word] += 1`), you may want to use:

```
string1 = 'here i go and i will see sun and enjoy the sunny day'
string2 = 'i will not go'
found = {}
new_words = {}

for word in string1.split():
    if word in string2.split():
        if word in found:
            found[word] += 1
        else:
            found[word] = 1
    else:
        if word in new_words:
            new_words[word] +=1
        else:
            new_words[word] = 1
```

Comment: I've update my answer, give it a try. Based on you question update, you've to change the order of the string you're looping from `string2`, `string1` to `string1`, `string2`

Comment: thanks a lot. it is working also fine but kvorobiev replied first so i accept his answer. but thanks you very much for help. .